# org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userDAO' is defined - context not being passed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, javabeans

Here are my files and my directory:

Spring-Module.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd"> 

<import resource="Spring-Datasource.xml" />
<import resource="Spring-User.xml" />
```

Spring-Datasource.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="VALID_URL" />
    <property name="username" value="USER" />
    <property name="password" value="PASS" />
</bean>
```

Spring-User.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd">

<bean id="userDAO" class="hello.JdbcUserDAO">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Application.java

```
package hello;
<import statements>
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context =
            new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDAO");
    }
}
```

RegistrationController.java

```
package hello;
@RestController
public class RegistrationController implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
//    @Autowired <-- using this instead of interface doesn't work either
private static ApplicationContext context;
private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response registerUser(@RequestParam Map<String,String> req) {


    User user = new User(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                        req.get("first"), req.get("last"), req.get("email"), 
                        req.get("age"), Double.parseDouble(req.get("height")), 
                        Double.parseDouble(req.get("weight")), Double.parseDouble(req.get("bmi"))
                        );

    UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDAO"); // <--- error here
    userDAO.insert(user);


    return new Response(counter.get(), "200");
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    this.context = ac;
    }

}
```

When I access the bean userDAO from the Application class, everything works perfectly and as expected. The problem is when I try to use the context to access userDAO from my route class, and it is throwing error 'bean userDAO not found'. Because of this I suspect that the context must be created again inside my route?

I am relatively new to Spring and completely stumped! I will try to clarify any questions you guys have.

### Edit: Added directory

```
   src/main/java/hello
      /resources
                /Spring-User.xml
                /Spring-Module.xml
                /Spring-Datasource.xml
```

Comment: it is because you are giving wrong bean name in controller class.. 
you should give context.getBean("userDAO"); instead of context.getBean("UserDAO");

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo while I was putting the question up. I've updated my code that I'm actually calling. 

I've been calling "userDAO"

Comment: try to use the following code to autowire applicationContext
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext context;

Comment: I had this code before, but I tried again and still same error. Do you have any idea what could cause the error?

Comment: You are loading your context, then start the spring boot application. You now have 2 unrelated application contexts. Instead of loading the context, just add `@ImportResource("classpath:Spring-Module.xml")' to your spring-boot application and remove the instantiation of your application context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution - thanks for the help. I'm not sure why this works (or rather, why implementing the interface doesn't work).

RegistrationController.java

```
package hello;


@RestController
public class RegistrationController implements ApplicationContextAware {

@Autowired
private static ApplicationContext context;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Response registerUser(@RequestParam Map<String,String> req) {
    context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml"); // <--- added this line


    User user = new User(counter.incrementAndGet(),
                    req.get("first"), req.get("last"), req.get("email"), 
                    req.get("age"), Double.parseDouble(req.get("height")), 
                    Double.parseDouble(req.get("weight")), Double.parseDouble(req.get("bmi"))
                    );

    UserDAO userDAO = (UserDAO) context.getBean("userDAO"); 
    userDAO.insert(user);


    return new Response(counter.get(), "200");
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
    return context;
}

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext ac) throws BeansException {
    this.context = ac;
    }

}
```

Comment: it's based on my answer and idea, you can follow and should work this. but don't upvote and posting answer is very disappointed to me. i will delete my answer now. good luck

Comment: Because i already request you to implement like this -- new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("Spring-Module.xml");

Comment: Yes, this is from your answer. The difference is you suggested making it a member variable rather than creating the variable inside the function - that seemed to make the difference. 

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's up to you, you can create any where, I suggest in global variable as to your used.

Comment: That isn't a solution... It will eventually break.

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to set up classpath scan for annotated components and turn on annotation config

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example.dao, com.example.service, com.example.controller, etc..."/>
```

But the best advice in 2016 is to totally forget xml configs and start using java configs.

Comment: Do you know why this works? I'm still new to Spring and am trying to learn how it works. 

Also, where is this code supposed to go? Thanks

Comment: your 2016 approach is good but question owner need to know about @Autowired and need to delete xml beans declaration. for the first time, I prefer XML first and then changed to annotations like your answer when he is matured.

Comment: Addition: People new to Spring framework may gets confused about which approach to follow. eg.XML or Annotations or Java Configs. As of now the Spring team is suggesting to follow JavaConfig based approach as it gives more flexibility. But there is no one-size fits all kind of solution. One has to choose the approach based on their own application needs.

Comment: @Steven it must go to your Spring-Module file. You tell the spring DI container that it must search the components in the specified packages and they are annotated classes. Instead, you can define each bean manually in the xml, which doesn't seem practical on a large codebase.